# Alamofire 5: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm getting this crash with Alamofire 5.0 CR3

[image: Alamofire crash]

Crash occurs in RequestTaskMap.swift from Alamofire library.

I do not have any stack trace, only a Firebase crash report, which I find it kinda useless.
[image: Firebase crash report]

I get this crash some of the time, on the same method, with same value.

```
func getUserDetails(for id: Int, success: @escaping(User) -> (), fail: @escaping failBlock) {
    APIClient.performRequest(for: UserDetailsRoute(userId: id)) { (response: Result<User, AFError>) in
        self.complete(response, success: success, fail: fail)
    }
}
```

Router:

```
struct UserDetailsRoute: Route {
    let userId: Int

    var methodType: HTTPMethod { return .get }
    var path: URL { return APIType.client.url.appendingPathComponent("/user/\(userId)") }
    var customHeaders: [String : String]?  { return [HTTPHeaderField.contentType.rawValue : ContentType.urlEncoded.rawValue] }
}
```

PerformRequest:

```
@discardableResult
func performRequest<T: Decodable>(for route: Route, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion: @escaping (Result<T, AFError>) -> Void) -> DataRequest {
    return sessionManager.request(NetworkRouter(route))
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseDecodable(decoder: decoder) { (response: DataResponse<T, AFError>) in
            completion(response.result)
    }
}
```

URLRequestConvertible:

```
struct NetworkRouter: URLRequestConvertible {

    let route: Route

    init(_ route: Route) {
        self.route = route
    }

    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: route.path)

        // HTTP Method
        urlRequest.httpMethod = route.methodType.rawValue

        // Common Headers

        urlRequest.setValue(NetworkConfig.CLIENT_ID, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.clientId.rawValue)
        urlRequest.setValue(AppSettings.shared.interfaceLanguage, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.acceptLanguage.rawValue)

        // Custom headers
        if let headers = route.customHeaders {
            for header in headers {
                urlRequest.setValue(header.value, forHTTPHeaderField: header.key)
            }
        }

        // Body
        if let route = route as? RouteBody {
            urlRequest.httpBody = route.data
        }

        // Parameters
        if let route = route as? RouteParameters {
            do {
                urlRequest = try route.encoder.encode(urlRequest, with: route.parameters)
            } catch {
                throw AFError.parameterEncodingFailed(reason: .customEncodingFailed(error: error))
            }
        }

        return urlRequest
    }

}
```

Any idea what can I do to fix this? I really dunno where to start.

// Edit 1: 
Adding Zombi Objects in AppScheme gives me: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Hmm

// Edit 2: 
[image: l]

// Edit 3:
Adding stack trace from **bt** command:

[image: bt stack trace]

Comment: How is `requestsToTasks` declared?

Comment: see my edited question.

Comment: u might check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837295/how-to-solve-this-exc-bad-accesscode-exc-i386-gpflt-in-swift-programming and cross check u code once

Comment: I do not see the relevance

Comment: Your crash stack doesn't seem to match the screenshot you provided, so they seem to be two different crashes.

Comment: In your first edit about enabling Zombie Objects, where are you seeing that crash?

Comment: Also, when you crash in Xcode, the debugger should be active and you can just type `bt` and return and that should give you the backtrace for your crash.

Comment: @JonShier, added the trace from bt. never knew about this command, so thank you for that :) Further analysing this issue, I see most of the time it reproduces on simulator :(

Comment: Seems like a crash within Swift's `Dictionary` type. Is only crashing with optimization turned on? Also, do a clean build and rebuild your dependencies.

Comment: Crashes occurs on Dev scheme where I do not have optimization level selected. clean build does not solve the problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sees to be a multi-threading issue. Are you using custom queues when creating the Session? Check if rootQueue is serial.

According to doc:

```
/// Root `DispatchQueue` for all internal callbacks and state update. **MUST** be a serial queue.
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a concurred queue as rootQueue. Thank you so much. Fixed by creating a serial queue and using it as a rootQueue one :)

Comment: Bro i have same isssue rootQueue value is OS_dispatch_queue_serial how can i change the serial